# How to select a specific record/row of data in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have my sql database Views available to my report, but sometimes they return multiple values, for example I have one that shows me the Total Credits for a range of years.

When I click "Browse Data.." it lets me see what bits of data are available
Eg:

```
Credits
-------
31
45
460
```

But I want to select 45 (based on a customer ID)... is it possible to do this?

EDIT: An alternative is if I can link the Customer ID from two views, but only if it's not null (as sometimes there are no records in the Credits)

Comment: "Browse Data" just shows you everything in the database for that field, not necessarily what's going to be in the report. If you want only a certain customer by ID why can't you just put `{table.customerId}=myCustomerID` in the record selection formula?

Comment: Ahh that explains why the browse data was confusing.

And woah, okay I must've made a typo last time I tried to do that because it didn't work before, but it works now. 

Thanks for the help Ryan!

Comment: Just tried it out, the problem is when one View/Year has no data and turns up null, it makes my whole report freak out and go blank.

Comment: What does your data model look like?

Comment: I have a CONTRACT_VIEW that has my Item Type, Customer_ID, Credit_Price, Credit_Qty (and some other stuff that's irrelevant)


Then I have several Views for each year such as TOTAL_2013 which has the Customer_ID, Credits, and Total (sum of costs).


The views are not linked with foreign keys in the database expert because that 'deletes' records I want if there are no purchases in one year.

I want to be able to grab the Credits for a year but for a particular Customer_ID

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem of unintentionally "deleting" customers from the report results, first do a left outer join between the CONTRACT_VIEW and the year views, such as TOTAL_2013. In your selection formula, instead of just doing something like `{TOTAL_2013.Customer_ID}=MyCustomerID`, add all the nulls to it as well, so: `isnull({TOTAL_2013.Customer_ID}) or {TOTAL_2013.Customer_ID}=MyCustomerID`. This will prevent customers who don't have any entries in the by-year views from being removed completely from the report.

Comment: Oh great I'll try that out!

And oh wow I never noticed the Link Options before...